# What's the common name for this Asset?

Tags: gui-design, login, users, profile

On google account you have the option to choose a little image that will show up every time you are logged in. This is quite common across many websites and apps etc.

Would you call this Avatar-Image? I am not sure how to name this.

Comment: If that is a real picture of the user, it can be called a user-thumbnail or profile-picture. Otherwise it is an avatar.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about just the image then it's commonly known as avatar, profile avatar or user account avatar.

Currently there's a trend of using a letter (usually the initial, sometimes 2 letters) for a neutral gender default avatar if the user hasn't selected one, instead of the previous generic-man-face and variations.

Comment: Yes just the Image. Super good input,thanks a lot for the Info. The Initials would be a perfect solution for the image if the user doesnt upload a picture

Comment: If you use initials, you might also consider coloring the background so that the avatars for all new users have some additional variety. Also, make sure you put them in first name, last name order or as determined by the convention in your area. (Looking at you Microsoft....)

Answer (score 0):

It's known and introduced as "User profile". While on design and exporting assets we identify it as a profile image and have a separate screen or pop up to showcase there is a profile/actions belongs to the user.

So you can simply name it as ***"Profile"***.

Comment: Thank you Niranjan! :-)

Comment: You are welcome @Mikeux